# Get date of nearest certain day of week

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, zend-date

I'm using Zend_Date to create dates.
How can I get date of the nearest further day of week, Monday, for example. I need to calculate it not only from now, but from any date.

Example. 
January, 31, Thursday.

I need to calculate date of the nearest Monday.

Result of function call should be February, 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i dont know in zend but surely you can use `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next monday'));` in php

Comment: Sorry. You answer is fine for today. But I need to use it from any date I want. I changed my question.

Comment: I found the solution date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next monday', strtotime('31.01.2013')));

Comment: @magalter  yes you can find time relative to any date.